# Rock-paper-scissors game - prompting user input via buttons for certain # of rounds?

Tags: javascript

Goal is to play five rounds.

For each round, player chooses action by clicking one of three buttons (rock, paper, or scissors), the computer chooses an action randomly, and the outcome of that round is logged.

However, my code ends up taking the player's first action, and then simulating five rounds against computer using the same player action for all five rounds.

```js
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.action').forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', e => {
      const outcome = game(e.target.id);
      if (outcome === -1)
        computerScore += 1;
      if (outcome === 1)
        playerScore += 1;
    });
  });
  i += 1;
}
if (i == 4) {
  console.log("Player score: ", playerScore);
  console.log("Computer score: ", computerScore);
}

function computerPlay() {
  const turnOutcome = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  switch (turnOutcome) {
    case 0:
      return "rock";
      break;
    case 1:
      return "paper";
      break;
    case 2:
      return "scissors";
      break;
  }
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
  computerSelection = computerSelection.toLowerCase();

  if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "paper")
    return -1;
  if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "scissors")
    return -1;
  if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "rock")
    return -1;
  if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "scissors")
    return 1;
  if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "rock")
    return 1;
  if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "paper")
    return 1;
  if (playerSelection === computerSelection)
    return 0;
}

function game(playerSelection) {
  console.log(playerSelection);
  computerSelection = computerPlay();
  const outcome = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
  console.log(outcome);
  return outcome;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="action-row">
    <button class="action" id="rock">Rock</button>
    <button class="action" id="paper">Paper</button>
    <button class="action" id="scissors">Scissors</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any hints/suggestions?

Also, am not sure why it's printing out final score before finishing the for loop.

---

Relevant portion of the code:

```js
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.action').forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', e => {
      const outcome = game(e.target.id);
      if (outcome === -1)
        computerScore += 1;
      if (outcome === 1)
        playerScore += 1;
    });
  });
  i += 1;
}
if (i == 4) {
  console.log("Player score: ", playerScore);
  console.log("Computer score: ", computerScore);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have the `while` loop. That's not running 5 rounds of the game, it's adding 5 listeners to each button. When you click a button, it will run all the listeners.

And the code that displays the scores is not running after they play all the games, it's running immediately after you add the listeners.

Event listeners are asynchronous, they're not like prompting for input. They don't wait for a click, they just save a function to run later when the click happens.

Add a listener to each button, and the listener should increment a global variable containing the round number. When the round goes past 5, end the game and display the score.

```js
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let round = 1;
const max_rounds = 5;

document.querySelectorAll('.action').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (round <= max_rounds) {
      const outcome = game(e.target.id);
      if (outcome === -1)
        computerScore += 1;
      else if (outcome === 1)
        playerScore += 1;
      round++;
      if (round == max_rounds) {
        console.log("Player score: ", playerScore);
        console.log("Computer score: ", computerScore);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This is a very common problem amongst new programmers introduced to javascript.

Comment: Very true, it's difficult to think asynchronously, even for experienced programmers.